# Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE Array = '4'

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

it's my first post...
I have a problem with a php file that was modifie, but not from me.
In a menu item i found this error:
1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE Array = '4'
And in another menu item I found this:
Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../home/templates/rt_nuance/html/com_tags/tag/default.php on line 113

This is my .php file:

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_tags
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Note that there are certain parts of this layout used only when there is exactly one tag.
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');
$isSingleTag = (count($this->item) == 1);
?>

<div class="tag-category<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">
 <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
  <h1>
   <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?>
  </h1>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php if ($this->params->get('show_tag_title', 1)) : ?>
  <h2>
   <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $this->tags_title, '', 'com_tag.tag'); ?>
  </h2>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php // We only show a tag description if there is a single tag. ?>
 <?php if (count($this->item) == 1 && (($this->params->get('tag_list_show_tag_image', 1)) || $this->params->get('tag_list_show_tag_description', 1))) : ?>
  <div class="category-desc">
   <?php $images = json_decode($this->item[0]->images); ?>
   <?php if ($this->params->get('tag_list_show_tag_image', 1) == 1 && !empty($images->image_fulltext)) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>">
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ($this->params->get('tag_list_show_tag_description') == 1 && $this->item[0]->description) : ?>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $this->item[0]->description, '', 'com_tags.tag'); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php // If there are multiple tags and a description or image has been supplied use that. ?>
 <?php if ($this->params->get('tag_list_show_tag_description', 1) || $this->params->get('show_description_image', 1)): ?>
  <?php if ($this->params->get('show_description_image', 1) == 1 && $this->params->get('tag_list_image')) : ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->params->get('tag_list_image'); ?>">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($this->params->get('tag_list_description', '') > '') : ?>
   <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $this->params->get('tag_list_description'), '', 'com_tags.tag'); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('items'); ?>
 <?php if (($this->params->def('show_pagination', 1) == 1 || ($this->params->get('show_pagination') == 2)) && ($this->pagination->get('pages.total') > 1)) : ?>
  <div class="pagination">
   <?php if ($this->params->def('show_pagination_results', 1)) : ?>
    <p class="counter pull-right"> <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?> </p>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    //j3 compatibility
    if(!defined('DS')){
        define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }

    JLoader::register('J2StoreController', JPATH_COMPONENT.'/controllers/controller.php');
    JLoader::register('J2StoreModel',  JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/models/model.php');
    JLoader::register('J2StoreView',  JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/views/view.php');

    require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/library/base.php');
    require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_j2store/helpers/utilities.php');
    require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/library/prices.php');
    require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/helpers/strapper.php');
    require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/version.php');
    require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_j2store/models/products.php');
    J2StoreStrapper::addJS();
    J2StoreStrapper::addCSS();

    $tes_prod = new J2StoreModelProducts();
    $tes_prod->setId('118');
    $test_item = $tes_prod->getItem();
    $test_data = J2StoreHelperCart::getItemInfo('118');;

    ?>
    <h1 style="color#f00">TAG</h1>

    <link href="<?php echo JURI::base().'media/j2store/css/j2store-product.css' ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.1.8/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
    <style>
        .sm-row-fluid :nth-child(3n+4){margin-left:0; clear: both; }
        .sm-row-fluid + table{display:none;}
        .j2store-item-title-link {display:block;}
    </style>
    <div class="row-fluid sm-row-fluid">
        <?php foreach( $this->items as $value):
            $this_prod_obj = new J2StoreModelProducts();
            $this_prod_obj->setId($value->content_item_id);
            $item = $this_prod_obj->getItem();
            $product = array(
                'id' => $value->content_item_id,
                'name' => $item->product_name,
                'main_image' => $item->main_image ,
                'price' => number_format ( $item->item_price, 2 ),
                'special_price' => number_format ( $item->special_price, 2 ),
                'discount' => number_format (  100-($item->special_price*100/$item->item_price), 0 ),
                'url' => JURI::base().'outfit/view/'.$value->content_item_id.'-'.$item->product_name
            );

            ?>

            <div class="span4 sm-product-box" >
                <div class="j2store-product-single j2store-product-single-113 column-1" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                    <!-- on Before display product -->
                    <div class="j2store-before-display-product">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Form action starts here -->
                    <form action="/carrello" method="post" name="j2storeProductForm" id="j2store-product-list" class="j2storeProductForm">
                        <!-- Before displaying product Images -->
                        <div class="j2store-before-display-productimages">
                        </div>

                        <a itemprop="url" class="j2store-item-title-link" href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>">
                            <img class="j2store-item-productlist-thumbimage" itemprop="image" src="<?php echo $product['main_image'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name'] ;?>">
                        </a>

                        <!-- Title -->
                        <h3 class="j2store-item-title" itemprop="name">
                            <a itemprop="url" class="j2store-item-title-link" href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>">
                                <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="sm-product-hoover" style="position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height:100%; display: none;">
                            <!-- Title -->
                            <h1 class="j2store-item-title" itemprop="name">
                                <a itemprop="url" class="j2store-item-title-link" href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>">
                                    <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
                                </a>
                            </h1>
                            <div class="j2store-product-prices">
                                <span class="j2store-product-item-label">Prezzo</span>
                                <?php if($product['special_price'] > 0) echo '<strike>';?>
                                <span itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
             <span itemprop="price" class="text" id="product_price_113"><?php echo $product['price'].' €'; ?></span>
                </span>
                                <?php if($product['special_price'] > 0): echo '</strike>';?>
                                    <span class="product-discount-offer" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <?php echo 'Sconto:'. $product['discount'].' %'; ?>
                    </span>
                                    <span itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                                    <span itemprop="price" id="product_special_price_113" class="product-special-price"><?php echo $product['special_price'].' €'; ?></span>
                                </span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <a id="addtoCartBtn" href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>" type="submit" class="j2store-item-cart-button button " value="Aggiungi al carrello">Aggiungi al carrello</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- end item -->
            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks to everyone...

Comment: Try to provide the exact line or place where you are getting the issue. It's hard for people to find out with code like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array where it needs to be a string in your query

Specifically, where there there should be a column name you are getting a PHP array. As a result, PHP converts that array to string that says "Array" before sending it off to MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! Unfortunately I don't understand this code... what I have to do?